# TypeScript - уникальность поля `id` каждого объекта в массиве

Tags: typescript

Возможно ли как-то TypeScript'ом задать такое ограничение (некий кастомный тип), чтобы в каждом объекте массива поле `id` содержало уникальное значение?

Валидный массив:

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

Невалидный массив:

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}]
```

Если такое возможно сделать, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От части возможно, при следующих условиях:

- Массив имеет тип кортежа
- Тип этого поля в каждом объекте должен быть литералом, то есть например `1` вместо `number`
- Тип будет проверяться функцией, при простом присваивании такое не проверить

Для начала определим тип для элементов кортежа:

```
type Identifiable<I extends number> = { id: I } // Предположим что id всегда число
```

Теперь напишем проверку уникальности элементов:

```
type IsDistinct<T extends readonly Identifiable<number>[], E = never> =
    T extends readonly [
        Identifiable<infer I>,
        ...infer Rest extends Identifiable<number>[]
    ]
        ? I extends E
            ? false
            : IsDistinct<Rest, E | I>
        : true
```

Здесь мы рекурсивно проходим по кортежу и проверяем есть ли тип `id` элемента в юнионе `E`. Если его там нет, добавляем его туда и идём дальше, иначе возвращаем `false`. Когда доходим до конца возвращаем `true`.

> Все массивы помечены как `readonly` для корректной работы с `as const`

Далее напишем функцию которая будет проверять тип значения:

```
// Вспомогательный тип для аргументов функции
type DistinctOnly<T extends readonly Identifiable<number>[]> = IsDistinct<T> extends true ? T : never

function ensureDistinct<T extends readonly Identifiable<number>[]>(arg: DistinctOnly<T>): T {
    return arg;
}
```

Проверим функцию на ваших примерах:

```
// Работает
ensureDistinct([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}])
// Тоже работает, потому что тип id выводится как number -> добавим as const
ensureDistinct([{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}]) 

ensureDistinct([{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}] as const) // OK
ensureDistinct([{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}] as const) // Ошибка!
```

Comment: Супер! Действительно работает. Но осталось несколько вопросов, буду рад, если поясните.

Comment: > Здесь мы рекурсивно проходим по кортежу и проверяем есть ли тип id элемента в юнионе E
А почему везде где используется `IsDistinct` ему не передается аргумент `E`? То есть берется его значение по умолчанию `never`. Получается, что мы всегда проверяем есть ли тип `id` элемента в `never`?

Comment: > Тип будет проверяться функцией, при простом присваивании такое не проверить
А почему так? Я понимаю, что функция компилируется в простой "байпасс", но все же. Основной идеей было как раз избавиться от любого валидационного кода на JS.

Comment: > То есть берется его значение по умолчанию never. Получается, что мы всегда проверяем есть ли тип id элемента в never?

Не всегда, а на первой итерации. Здесь never выступает в роли пустого юниона.

Comment: > Здесь never выступает в роли пустого юниона.
Точно, упустил этот момент.
И еще вопрос появился. А возможно ли сделать проверку уникальности по 2 полям сразу? То есть чтобы, например, и `id` и `url` были уникальными? И если хотя бы один из них не уникален, то проверка не проходит?

Comment: > А почему так? Я понимаю, что функция компилируется в простой "байпасс", но все же. Основной идеей было как раз избавиться от любого валидационного кода на JS.
Потому что здесь описан не сам тип объекта, а валидатор для готовых типов, проверяющий соответствие вашим условиям. При вызове функции тип аргумента выводится автоматически, затем он подставляется в валидатор. При присваивании такое поведение невозможно, так как тс не знает тип объекта до, собственно, присваивания.

Comment: > И еще вопрос появился. А возможно ли сделать проверку уникальности по 2 полям сразу? 
Можно по аналогии с `E` добавить ещё один параметр для валидации другого поля. Можно просто написать второй такой тип и применить композицию. Можно вообще обобщить всё это дело - что-то вроде `DistinctOnlyBy<DistincyOnlyBy<T, "a">, "b">`.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать.